# Avoid restart in Rails production environment to see changes saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sometimes I have to start our application server with the production environment. It always has surprised me that changes saved on development are instantly loaded, while those made on production environment aren't.

What is the reason behind it? How can I change it so anything saved is "seen" on the server?

Thanks.

Comment: It is probably cache, take a look at your `config/environments/production.rb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on purpose. Reloading the code between each request requires a reasonable amount of time and resources, therefore it's not advisable for a production environment.

You can change the setting from the `production.rb` environment configuration

```
# Code is not reloaded between requests.
config.cache_classes = true
```

Change it to `false`.

I suggest you to not make the change permanent on production, rather just toggle the value temporarily if you need to quick check something.